# How to display the date month and year in a specific format using javascript and react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

i have the date in this format

const title = "2020-08-23T00:00:00.000Z"

i want to display this as August 19th, 2020

i have tried using below

```
<div>{moment(title).format('MMMM D')</div>
```

and this gives output like below

August 19

how can i modify the above to get output like August 19th, 2020 using javascript.

could someone help me with this.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
moment(yourString).format('MMMM Do, YYYY');
```

Where:
'MMMM' --> month, capital, full length

'Do'   --> day with order

'YYYY' --> year

Answer (score 2):

To format date like "August 19th, 2020" use:

```
moment().format("MMMM Do, YYYY")
```

Read the documentation to find more about different [date formatting options](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).